# How to get TouchSensor nested under joint in Webots (Python API)

Tags: python, sensors, webots

I wish to have a touchsensor on the end of a moving arm. However, through the Python API, getDevice('touch_sensor') only returns sensors that are directly under the Robot parent.

Is there a way I can either get a sensor that is nested (under a joint), or instead make a sensor that is under parent move in tandem with another joint?

I have tried setting the bounding box of the sensor to a shape/transform nested under the moving joint, but it simply takes on the original position of the shape and doesn't update when the joint moves.

I have also tried putting the sensor directly under the joint, in which case it does indeed move, but then I cannot access it from the python API. (Using get device returns None)

Comment: I should mention, I'm on R2019a.r1 on Ubuntu 18.1 x64

Comment: I looked at the hoap2_sumo.wbt demo and saw that they indeed nest sensors under hinged bodies. So perhaps this is a bug, or a limitation of the Python API?

Comment: I tried adding a python controller to hoap2_sumo.wbt and robot.getDevice("left sensor") returns None.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem, I should have used getTouchSensor instead of getDevice!!

Now it works fine.